# Javascript chunked file upload to PHP Server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, fileapi

So I have this function in javascript to send parts of file to server:

```
function ajaxPartUpload(url, packageNo, file, attachmentId)
        {
            var packageMaxSize = 10240; //1048576; //10485760; //reduced for tests
            var packageCount =  Math.ceil(file.size / packageMaxSize);
            var start = packageNo * packageMaxSize;
            var stop = (packageNo+1) * packageMaxSize - 1; 
            if ((packageNo+1) === packageCount || packageCount === 0) {
                stop = file.size - 1;
            }
            var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
            var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
                var data = {
                    blob: reader.result,
                    partNo: packageNo,
                    lastPartNo: packageCount,
                    fileName: file.name,
                    fileType: file.type,
                    fileSize: file.size,
                    attachmentId: attachmentId,
                    multipart: true
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.continue === false) {

                            return true;
                        } else {
                            ajaxPartUpload(url, packageNo+1, file, response.attachmentId);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    }
```

And It's working as expected, I get in post the binary data of files I'm sending.
Under specified url I have script that basicly do this:

```
$attachment = V()->Attachment->find($_POST['attachmentId']);
        $destination_path = $attachment->getPath();
    $filePointer = fopen($destination_path, 'a');
            $written = fwrite($filePointer, $_POST['blob']);
            if ($written == false )
            {
                throw new Exception('File data not written');
            }
            fclose($filePointer);
```

And as long as I have text files it's ok, but when I try to send binary file, the files I'm reciving are about 50% bigger in size, and corrupted, it doesn't matter if I make chunk size big enough to hold all file in one http request or not. What I'm doing wrong?

I have dumped length of 'blob' in javascript right before send and length of recived blob in php: I've got 2 compleatly diffrent results for one chunk max 1 MB file has '28KB' (got from ls -lash):

javascript: 25755

php: 36495

What happend? When I've tired text file all was ok.

@EDIT:
Solution
in JS change:

```
blob: reader.result,
```

to

```
blob: window.btoa(reader.result),
```

AND in PHP

```
$written = fwrite($filePointer, $_POST['blob']);
```

to

```
$written = fwrite($filePointer, base64_decode($_POST['blob']));
```

that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added atob in javascript on my result from reader, and then decoded data before reading with base64_decode. It solves the problem.

The problem is that PHP interprets this binary data in some other way, as string perhaps, I don't really know. Anyway sending a 'bit' bigger encoded data saves a lot of nerves.

Comment: Please add the solution code to your answer, then you can mark your answer as the accepted one (green mark). Glad to hear you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your file with the 'b' flag, as it's recommended by PHP docs:

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php :

> For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().

So be it:

```
$filePointer = fopen($destination_path, 'ab');
```

If your problem continues, then it's probably due to concurrency problems, so you should guard the above call with some lock so to be sure there aren't different php processes writing at the same time to that file.

You can use [**flock()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) for that, check out how to use it in this [**flock tutorial**](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0).

Comment: I'm sure that there are no other processes working, with that file. I've added b as sugested but it didn't help.

Comment: You can also try `$written = fwrite($filePointer, $_POST['blob'], strlen($_POST['blob']));`

Comment: Well I've tried some 'strlen' magic, and I've putted the result.